# Hotkey to run program in SAS?

Tags: sas

I know in R I can use control+r to run my program code.  I am wondering if there is an equivalent hotkey in SAS?  If not, is there a way to 'program' one into SAS?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The default hot key for run (submit program) is the F8 key.

If you're using Base SAS (not EG), then you can type 'keys' into the box in the upper left hand corner, or by default hit F9, and bring up a window where you can set most of your hotkeys.  You can also customize the toolbar buttons at the top of the window by right clicking on the toolbar and selecting 'customize'.

See http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi28/240-28.pdf for more options.

Comment: I like to change my F3 (or F8) key to `clear log;submit;` which will clear the log prior to submitting everytime.  Leads to less confusion as I don't need to search through the log to find just the piece I'm interested in.  If I want to submit without clearing the log I change my ALT-F3 (or ALT-F8) key to just `submit`.

Comment: As I submit a lot of code to a remote SAS server, I set CTRL-F3 to `rsubmit;`

Comment: @Rob Penridge One question: I changed the DMKEYS file in such way that I entered clear log; submit; for F2 and F5 key. For the F5 key it works, but if I press F2 nothing happens? Why does it not work with my F2 key?

Comment: @StatTistician Good question but I'm afraid I have no idea why it behaves this way.  I just tried it too and have the same issue as you do.  Good thing I'm used to using F3 =)